# Outlook email address format: is there an equivalent of + in gmail?

Tags: email, outlook, email-address

When I want to send something to a gsuite / gmail address, I can do username@domain.com, or username+randomstring@domain.com, or any other random string after +. Is there a similar equivalent in outlook?